# Rails has_many foreign key producing empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, has-many

I'm can't figure out some weird behaviour that im getting in the rials console while I'm testing out some code.

My models are as follows:

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name


  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true

end
```

company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :employees, :foreign_key => 'company_id', :class_name => "Profile"
  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: true

end
```

I enter the rails console

```
$rails c --sandbox
```

and then test the following code

```
:001 > company = Company.find(2)
Company Load (4.2ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = ?     LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<Company id: 2, name: "Jet Star", created_at: "2012-06-24 04:12:50", updated_at:  "2012-06-24 04:12:50"> 
:002 > employee = Profile.find(5)
Profile Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
=> #<Profile id: 5, user_id: 5, first_name: "Douglas", last_name: "Reed", created_at: "2012-06-17 15:05:58", updated_at: "2012-06-17 15:05:58", deleted: false, company_id: nil> 
:003 > employee.company = company
=> #<Company id: 2, name: "Jet Star", created_at: "2012-06-24 04:12:50", updated_at: "2012-06-24 04:12:50"> 
:004 > employee.company
=> #<Company id: 2, name: "Jet Star", created_at: "2012-06-24 04:12:50", updated_at: "2012-06-24 04:12:50"> 
:005 > employee
=> #<Profile id: 5, user_id: 5, first_name: "Douglas", last_name: "Reed", created_at:  "2012-06-17 15:05:58", updated_at: "2012-06-17 15:05:58", deleted: false, company_id: 2> 
:006 > company.employees
Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."company_id" = 2
=> [] 
:007 > Profile.find_by_company_id(2)
Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."company_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
 => nil 
:008 > employee.save
(0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
(0.4ms)  UPDATE "profiles" SET "company_id" = 2, "updated_at" = '2012-06-24 07:35:14.525138' WHERE "profiles"."id" = 5
(0.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> true 
:009 > company.employees
=> []  
:010 > Profile.find_by_company_id(2)
  Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."company_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
=> #<Profile id: 5, user_id: 5, first_name: "Douglas", last_name: "Reed", created_at: "2012-06-17 15:05:58", updated_at: "2012-06-24 07:35:14", deleted: false, company_id: 2>
```

If you look up the profile record it shows the company_id, but when you do a search for employees(profiles)with that id nothing is returned.

so why won't company.employees return a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
company.reload
company.employees
```

Comment: will I need to do this my controllers or is this something that only needs to be done in the console?

Comment: If all of that same code were in a single controller, then yes you would have to `reload` the `company` instance so that you get the correct information from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Writing 'employee.company =company' only sets the company id of the employee in memory. When you query company.employee it searches through the employee table (on disk) but doesn't find the id there because the change hasn't been committed yet.

Comment: I have updated the details of the question. As you can see I saved the record but even after I try to access a list of employees the array in empty

Comment: How is 'employees' defined in Company?

Comment: In the has_many relationship, because I makes more sense to say the a company has many employees, but the actual records are stored in the profiles table